# Custom Javascript not functioning in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I just created some custom JavaScript (at first) which generates a sum of checked fields.

However, when I implement it in WordPress - it does nothing. I guess I'm overlooking something, but I can't seem to be able to figure it out.

**This is my JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function show_selected_item_val($item)
{
    var res1 = 0, res2 = 0, res3 = 0, res4 = 0, res5 = 0, res6 = 0, res7 = 0, res8 = 0, res9 = 0, res10 = 0; 
    var res11 = 0, res12 = 0, res13 = 0, res14 = 0, res15 = 0, res16 = 0, res17 = 0, res18 = 0; 
    if(document.all['Q1'][0].checked)        res1 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q2'][0].checked)        res2 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q3'][0].checked)        res3 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q4'][0].checked)        res4 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q5'][0].checked)        res5 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q6'][0].checked)        res6 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q7'][0].checked)        res7 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q8'][0].checked)        res8 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q9'][0].checked)        res9 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q10'][0].checked)     res10 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q11'][0].checked)     res11 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q12'][0].checked)     res12 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q13'][0].checked)     res13 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q14'][0].checked)     res14 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q15'][0].checked)     res15 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q16'][0].checked)     res16 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q17'][0].checked)     res17 = 1;
    if(document.all['Q18'][0].checked)     res18 = 1;

    document.getElementById("show_content").innerHTML= res1 + res2 + res3 + res4 + res5 + res6 + res7 + res8 + res9 + res10 + res11 + res12 + res13 + res14 + res15 + res16 + res17 + res18;
}
//-->
</script>
```

**This is the HTML:**

```
<table>
       <tr>
       <td>
          <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="1" onClick="show_selected_item_val(this)"/>yes
          <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="0" onClick="show_selected_item_val(this)"/>no
       </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>
          <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="1" onClick="show_selected_item_val(this)"/>yes
          <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="0" onClick="show_selected_item_val(this)"/>no
       </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>
          <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="1" onClick="show_selected_item_val(this)"/>yes
          <input type="radio" name="Q3" value="0" onClick="show_selected_item_val(this)"/>no
       </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>
          <input type="radio" name="Q4" value="1" onClick="show_selected_item_val(this)"/>yes
          <input type="radio" name="Q4" value="0" onClick="show_selected_item_val(this)"/>no
       </td>
       </tr>

       ...

</table>

the result is: <span id="show_content">
```

I'm loading the JavaScript through the `functions.php` file. I checked, and it does load.
The results just don't show up.

So I'm guessing the handling of the script is not correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you to tag in an appropiate way. This is not java.

Comment: So, where do you actually call the function show_selected_item_val?

Comment: Read tag description before adding it: _Java_ ***(not to be confused with JavaScript)*** _[...]_. Your code is JavaScript, not java.

Comment: @fred02138 it's called on every radio button. OP, are there any error messages on the browser's javascript console ?

Comment: Remove the comment tag from the function

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/4CFcy/

I deleted the $item parameter in the function and the this argument in the function call
E.g.:

```
function show_selected_item_val()
```

...

```
<input type="radio" name="Q2" value="1" onClick="show_selected_item_val()"/>yes
<input type="radio" name="Q2" value="0" onClick="show_selected_item_val()"/>no
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something more like this:

```
function show_selected_item_val() {
    var score = 0
    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByName('Q' + i)[0].checked) {
            score++;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("show_content").innerHTML = score;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BhEAq/